# Camera stabilisers compatible with shooting in portrait

Tags: stabilisation

We shoot all our videos in portrait using a Canon 5D camera. What is the best type of camera stabliser for this scenario? Most I've seen only cater for shots in "landscape".

Comment: Could you add the model names of your existing cameras to the question? And do you plan to buy a new camera or are you looking for a stabilization that is built around these existing cameras?

Comment: We using a Canon 5D and not planning to buy a new camera. I'll update the question information... thanks so much for the feedback!

Comment: Could you add a right angle bracket to the mount of an existing stabiliser. Just a bit of steel would do it. The stabiliser would have to be large enough, but looking at the one we've got (DJI Ronin) I'd say it would be do-able.